# Running a PyQt4 script without a display

Tags: python, qt4, pyqt4

I would like to run a Python script that normally opens a Qt window remotely over a connection with no X11 forwarding. Is there any way to create some kind of virtual display that the window drawing can be sent to? (some x11-equivalent of /dev/null). The purpose of this is to check that a script works with the API of PyQt4 for different versions of PyQt4, but I want to be able to run this remotely on a server with no display. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You can install the xvfb utility

```
sudo apt-get install xvfb
```

and then start python scripts as:

```
xvfb-run python myscript.py
```

Or if you need to start the virtual display from code, xvfb is still needed to be installed, and additionally get the pyvirtualdisplay python package

```
pip install pyvirtualdisplay
```

And then before you create any qt component instances, add this:

```
from pyvirtualdisplay import Display
display = Display(visible=False, size=(1024, 768), color_depth=24)
display.start()
```

Answer (score 0):

Run a VNC server on the machine; it will start an instance of `Xfb`, a in-memory version of an X server.