# Run a executable PyQt5 python program without a display

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, pyqt

I need to run a executable PyQT5 python program without connect to any display on my Raspberry Pi on startup.
I found this post below:
[Running a PyQt4 script without a display](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12462796/running-a-pyqt4-script-without-a-display)

I tried to run it with putty and not connecting to any display, it works.
But if I add the instruction into autostart file in lxsession folder and boot up the Pi without any display, it unable to autostart.

Note: I had tested to execute compiled python file in autostart, but the application cant start without a display connect to. I tried using putty to execute in terminal and it shows

> pyqt could not connect to any x display

my command to run the application is as following:

> xvfb-run python3 /home/pi/System_scanning/program_Execute.py

for compiled executable command is as following:

> xvfb-run /home/pi/System_scanning/program_Execute

Now, that i need to run the executable file when startup without connect to any display.
I had added the command to

> /home/pi/.config/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart

for auto start when booting, but it only works when my Raspberry Pi connected to monitor during boot up. If i remove the monitor and boot up, the application is not running, unless i log in with putty and execute the command manually.

Comment: Please show the commands, how you started `xvfb-run` and the executable.

Comment: Hi, @MauriceMeyer, my command is as following: xvfb-run python3 /home/pi/System_scanning/program_Execute.py

Comment: @MauriceMeyer, if i execute the executable file it will be the command as following: sudo /home/pi/System_scanning/program_Execute

Comment: You are not using `xvfb-run` with the executable.

Comment: @MauriceMeyer, yes, because xvfb-run unable to run the executable file, it only able to run python file.

Comment: What means _unable_ ? What's the error message ?

Comment: @MauriceMeyer, sorry, my bad, after checking the error code again, i realize i typed wrong in my command. i forgot to remove the "python3 " from it. Now i am able to run the executable file with xvfb-run  commnad.
however, if my raspberry pi is not connected to any display, the program still wont auto start when boot up. Is there any way to solve this?

Comment: Please update your question, to make clear what you changed and which error message you get.

Comment: @MauriceMeyer, Hi, thank you for your advice. had updated as suggested. Now the issue is when connected to a display during boot up, the application able to autorun, but if boot up without display, then the application is not running till i log in using putty to execute the command manually.